# Prevent an aliased adress to show in nslookup

Tags: linux, ip

I have a settings where eth0 as two address :

```
# ip address show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:73:e6:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.42/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 6422sec preferred_lft 6422sec
    inet 192.168.123.252/32 scope global eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On the host, when doing a lookup for my own hostname, here is what is returned :

```
Name:      ispcu-7
Address 1: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe73:e68b%eth0 ispcu-7
Address 2: 192.168.1.42 ispcu-7
Address 3: 192.168.123.252 ispcu-7
```

So far so good.
How can I exclude address 3 to show in the above output ?

Comment: What is the command you use for looking up for your own hostname? What is the function of the additional IP address?

Comment: I use nslookup, and the additional address is used as a backup address

Comment: You need to remove the A record from your DNS zone for the domain name you are looking up with `nslookup`. I don't see any point in using a backup address from a completely separate subnet which is not reachable from outside.